# Inline encoding of image data on multiple sub-domains

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, subdomain, base64

I am attempting to replace all img tags in a webpage with the base64 encoded data contained in the image.

An image that is represented as:

```
<img src="http://a.example.com" />
```

would be changed to:

```
<img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGg..." />
```

The webpage contains images from multiple sub-domains, e.g.

```
<img src="http://a.example.com" />
<img src="http://b.example.com" />
```

On a single sub-domain I can use:

```
var images = document.getElementsByTagName('img');
for(var i=0; i<images.length; i++){
 var img = new Image();
 img.src = images[i].src;
 // Create canvas tag to represent img
 var canvas = document.createElement("canvas"); 
 canvas.width = img.width; 
 canvas.height = img.height;
 var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
 context.drawImage(img,0,0);

 img.src = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
 $(images[i]).replaceWith(img);
}
```

however, when the images are in a sub-domain other than that of the HTML page, I get:

```
Uncaught Error: SECURITY_ERR: DOM Exception 18
```

in the console. How do I perform this operation on a page to convert all image references with their respective encoded data?

Comment: This is something you should typically render on the backend, before the page is parsed.
I'm not sure what you are gaining by doing this on the client side.

Comment: I do not control the backend. I am trying to create a client-side solution to savings the webpage as a single resource.

Comment: Modifying the DOM using javascript doesn't actually change the HTML source, and doesn't create a single point of truth (since it is stateless).

Comment: The above approach works on a single (sub-)domain. I am hoping it is possible or someone can at least point me in the right direction. Please let me know if you have any insight on how to conquer this problem.

Answer (score 2):

You are violating the laws of the spec which state that if you use `drawImage` with an image that is not of the same origin as that of the canvas's document then the *orgin-clean* flag is set to false. From then onwards you are not allowed to use `toDataURL`. The spec's full words on the matter are [here.](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/the-canvas-element.html#security-with-canvas-elements)

The reason for this security is to prevent something called information leakage. To see why this is bad, consider the following hypothetical situation:

Say you are on a work network and so you have access to internal, private company sites and your (private!) hard-drive from your browser. The private sites might be something like `www.internal.myCompany.com` and your hard drive would be accessible from urls like `file:///C:/SomeOfMyPhotos/`.

Now suppose you visited a website with a hidden canvas and while you were browsing the site that canvas was constantly calling `drawImage()` onto that canvas with urls that it was guessing might exist. These urls would be things like an image on the private subdomain:

`www.internal.myCompany.com/secret/secret-plans.jpg`

Or an image on your hard drive:

`file:///C:/SomeOfMyPhotos/thatEmbarassingPhoto.png`

The malicious site would keep trying different combinations of private-to-you urls until it found one that was actually a file. Then it would draw it to the canvas. Then it would get the `imageData` from the canvas and send it off to the server.

Voila! They have stolen your secret plans and your embarassing photos, much without your consent.

Now we know that the above scenario is not very probable: After all, secret plans are almost always in PNG format whereas embarassing photos are nearly always in JPG format. But it stands that situations like the above could happen and so the security implications must take this into account.

Comment: I understand this is a security violation but what I hope to do is have the webpage contain all information needed to re-display it in a browser from a single HTML file. By encoding the image data into the HTML file (and the appropriate CSS, but that's another issue), I should be able to view the content again if the file were displayed on my local hard drive. Do you know of a way to accomplish this? Encoding the data in the way described in the question is the approach I am currently taking.

Comment: Well, if you only need to access files from two subdomains you own, you can change their CORs options to solve your problem. See: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-Origin_Resource_Sharing and more importantly: http://enable-cors.org/

Comment: Insightful response. I am using canvas simply to convert the image to base64 with the result being placed in the image's src attribute. I can change the image's src attribute to something like https://www.google.com/intl/en_com/images/srpr/logo3w.png but not an encoded string? Is there another way to convert this image's data to an encoded string aside from canvas, which I then could write to the src attribute like the aforementioned Google logo image example?

Answer (score 1):

The security sandbox will not let you call `toDataURL` on a canvas if it has had an image from another domain drawn on it. The exact logic escapes me, but it exists to prevent you from doing exactly this.

Comment: If a site like Facebook had an endpoint that showed the user a profile photo, this is a nice thing but should still be considered private information to the website. If the site could simply get the avatar by using functions like that, it would be a major risk to privacy.

Answer (score 1):

Generally you cannot read image data from [other domains](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CORS_Enabled_Image).  It violates the Cross-Origin Resource Sharing ([CORS](http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/)) security model.  That said you can get around this issue by having each subdomain use a [HTTP access control header](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/HTTP_access_control#Access-Control-Allow-Origin) (here's an [example](http://xavi.co/articles/get-around-cross-domain-restrictions) with [node.js](http://nodejs.org)) as well as setting the [`crossorigin`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML/Element/img#attr-crossorigin) attribute to `use-credentials` on each image tag.  Note that not all browsers support the `crossorigin` attribute.

Ultimately, both the server and client have to opt-in to get around CORS security for images.

Another work-around entails using a jquery plugin called [`$.getImageData`](http://www.maxnov.com/getimagedata/).  Under the covers this plugin uses a third party service called [img-to-json](http://img-to-json.appspot.com) and [JSONP](http://json-p.org/) to get around the security issues.  Here's a concrete example of how to use img-to-json:

```
"//img-to-json.appspot.com/?url=" + escape(img_url) + "&callback=" + callback
```

Basically, the service takes two parameters: the URL of the image you're downloading (which needs to be URL escaped), and the name of the callback you want executed when the image is done loading.  The callback is passed an objected with the [data url](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/data_URIs) version of the image as well as some metadata such as the height and width of the image.

Also, note the URL above is an example of a [protocol relative](http://paulirish.com/2010/the-protocol-relative-url/) URL (i.e. it begins with `//`), which means it'll worked on both `http` or `https` pages.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I was hoping for this method to work on any arbitrary website, even those to which I don't have access to the server to make the crossorigin change. The img-to-json approach looks interesting but I believe it will not be suitable if the website is not accessible from the appspot page; say, if I were to apply the company intranet page. This was part of the reason that I need a client-side solution.

Comment: You're right, the `img-to-json` solution does have some significant restrictions.  The only solution I see (without being able to set the server's HTTP headers) is to require some kind of user interaction.  Like asking them to manually upload the image to a server or to drag-and-drop an image over a specified area...